# how to put search form in navbar-header also in small size in bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, forms, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

i used bootstrap navbar and put a search (form) in it. but when i decrease the screen width , my form disappear and has been shown in the "Hamburger Menu".
but i want to show it in header in every widths...

Thank so much

structure in small is okay!
[image: structure in small is okay!]

but structure in large is inappropriate :-(
[image]

i need search box align left in large size.

```
        <div class="row" id="navrow" style="margin-bottom: -20px;">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                  <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                  </button>
                  <form class="navbar-form pull-right navbar-brand" role="search" style="display:block;">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="جستجو...">
                    </div>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">
                        <span class="icon-search" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                    </button>
                  </form>                     
                </div>
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                  <ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-right">
                    <li><a href="#">
                        <span class="icon-home" aria-hidden="true"></span> صفحه اصلی
                    </a></li>
                    <li class="hidden-xs hidden-sm nav-divide"></li>
                    <li><a href="#">
                        <span class="icon-order" aria-hidden="true"></span> سفارش ساخت
                    </a></li>
                    <li class="hidden-xs hidden-sm nav-divide"></li>
                    <li><a href="#">
                        <span class="icon-about" aria-hidden="true"></span> درباره ما
                    </a></li>
                    <li class="hidden-xs hidden-sm nav-divide"></li>
                    <li><a href="#">
                        <span class="icon-contact" aria-hidden="true"></span> تماس با ما
                    </a></li>
                  </ul>      
                </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
            </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
        </nav>
    </div><!-- /div#navrow -->
```

And The CSS is :

```
.main>#navrow>nav{
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #41065e , #701d98);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #41065e, #701d98);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #41065e, #701d98);
  background: linear-gradient(to top, #41065e , #701d98);
  border-radius: 10px 10px 0 0;
  border: none;
}
.main>#navrow div.navbar-collapse{
  margin: 8px 0;
  border:none;
}
.main>#navrow form.navbar-form{
  border:none;
  box-shadow: none;
  margin-top: 10px;  
  padding: 0px 20px;
}
.main>#navrow ul li:hover>a{
  background-color: #8245a0 !important;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
.main>#navrow ul li>a{
  color: white;
}
.main>#navrow ul li span.glyphicon{
  top: 4px;
  right: -7px;
}
.main>#navrow form{
  position: relative;
}
.main>#navrow form input{
  font-size: 1.7rem;
  padding: 7px;
  background-color: #41065e;
  color: #c5c5c5;
  border: none;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 3px 0px #FBFBFB;
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 3px 0px #FBFBFB;
  box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 3px 0px #FBFBFB;
}
.main>#navrow form button[type="submit"]{
  position: absolute;
  left: 10px;
  top: 0;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: none;
  font-size: 2rem;
  color: #c5c5c5;
}
```

Comment: Where is your code part,Please include to sort your fault

Comment: @Vijay Codes Added just now :-)

Comment: @ Reza Majidi, problem goes to your css page,and i also need that or go through  http://jsfiddle.net/ and make a fiddle code,then attach to your question.thnks

Comment: @ Reza Majidi, I cant get an idea about your page,Take a look at this fiddle code     http://jsfiddle.net/S9WQv/447/     and add your full code and update it.and send me  Remember frnd...Not a piece of code..FULL HTML PAGE CODE.

Comment: Did you see this fiddle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an [Input Group](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#input-groups) to attach the search button to the input field and add some custom CSS to position the search field.

```css
/**Custom**/

.navbar.navbar-custom {
  height: 50px;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #41065e, #701d98);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #41065e, #701d98);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #41065e, #701d98);
  background: linear-gradient(to top, #41065e, #701d98);
  border-radius: 10px 10px 0 0;
  border: none;
}
.navbar-custom .formSearch {
  width: 300px;
  float: left;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  padding-top: 7px;
}
.navbar-custom .form-control {
  font-size: 1.7rem;
  padding: 7px;
  background-color: #41065e;
  color: #c5c5c5;
  outline: none;
  border: none;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 3px 0px #FBFBFB;
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 3px 0px #FBFBFB;
  box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 3px 0px #FBFBFB;
}
.navbar-custom .inner-addon {
  position: relative;
}
.navbar-custom .inner-addon .glyphicon {
  position: absolute;
  padding: 10px;
  pointer-events: none;
  color: white;
}
.navbar-custom .left-addon .glyphicon {
  left: 0px;
}
.navbar-custom .left-addon input {
  padding-left: 30px;
}
.navbar-custom .navbar-header .navbar-toggle,
.navbar-custom .navbar-header .navbar-toggle:hover,
.navbar-custom .navbar-header .navbar-toggle:focus {
  border: none;
  background: none;
}
.navbar-custom .navbar-header .navbar-toggle .icon-bar {
  background: white;
}
.navbar-custom .collapse .navbar-nav > li > a {
  color: white;
}
.navbar-custom .collapse .navbar-nav > li:hover {
  background-color: #8245a0;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .navbar-custom .formSearch {
    padding-right: 15px;
    width: 70%;
  }
  .navbar-custom .navbar-collapse {
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #41065e, #701d98);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #41065e, #701d98);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #41065e, #701d98);
    background: linear-gradient(to top, #41065e, #701d98);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-rtl/3.2.0-rc2/css/bootstrap-rtl.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-custom">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false"> <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>

      </button>
      <form class="formSearch" role="search">
        <div class="inner-addon left-addon"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>

          <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="جستجو...">
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-left">
        <li>
          <a href="#">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home" aria-hidden="true"></span> صفحه اصلی
          </a>

        </li>
        <li class="hidden-xs hidden-sm nav-divide"></li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user" aria-hidden="true"></span> سفارش ساخت
          </a>

        </li>
        <li class="hidden-xs hidden-sm nav-divide"></li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog" aria-hidden="true"></span> درباره ما
          </a>

        </li>
        <li class="hidden-xs hidden-sm nav-divide"></li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-earphone" aria-hidden="true"></span> تماس با ما
          </a>

        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div>
  <!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
```

Comment: I Use Bootstrap.rtl and my search box is still in the right (in Large screen)
But in small screen its okay.

Answer (score 0):

As you can did in your code, you may use `hidden` and `visible` classes.

This is not the best solution, but you can hide/show. 
Here is a simple [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xcbxb7er/)

**The solution :**

Inside `navbar-header` :

```
<div class="navbar-header">
   <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
      <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button>

  <div class="col-xs-6 visible-xs">
   <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
  </div>
</div>
```

Inside a `navbar-collapse` :

```
<li class="hidden-xs">
  <div class="col-xs-12">
     <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
  </div>
</li>
```

Hope it helps ;)

Comment: u suggest using to forms?
one in xs-sm
another in md-lg??

Comment: As I said that's not the best solution but without jquery I don't know to do it. This is just an input not a part of your website.